# About the Ordering of Answers

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, accepted-answer

I found this question "[A question about hyperbolic functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/74468/19341)", where the OP accepted his own answer with no upvotes (so far). The strange thing is that the accepted answer doesn't show up on top, no matter how you sort it.

When I look at one of my own self-accepted answers, like this here
"[Two Steps away from the Hamilton Cycle](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/261069/19341)" my answer is top.

What's up with this post? Or is it just me seeing this...?

PS: When was the mapping from pure M.SE shared links to post names introduced? Cool thing...

Comment: Self-answered don't bump to the top when accepted, that's common knowledge (and was mentioned before on this very meta). The automatic name parser is quite old as well, but I can't recall when it started.

Comment: @AsafKaragila but mine did (bump). Where's the difference? ... Ahh no I got the "active" sorting at my question. Ok I think this solves my confusion. Thx...